# How can I disallow updates except for on one field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been preventing updates to certain models by using this in the model:

```
def update
  self.errors.add_to_base( "Cannot update a #{ self.to_s }" )
end
```

I'm now writing a plugin that delivers some extra functionality to the model, and I need to update one field in the model. If I weren't using a plugin I would do this directly in the model...

```
def update
  if self.changed == ['my_field']
    super
  else
    self.errors.add_to_base( "Cannot update a #{ self.to_s }" )       
  end
end
```

I can't do the same from my plugin since I don't know if the update behaviour is the ActiveRecord default, or has been overridden to prevent updates. Is there another way to prevent record updates while allowing me to override for a specific field (and only in the instance where my plugin is applied to this model).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you should be using a before_update callback for that sort of thing rather than overriding update. Second, you can store the updatable attributes on the model, and then update them with the plugin. I just wrote this in the browser, so it could be wrong.

```
  attr_accessor :updatable_attributes
  before_update :prevent_update

  private
  def prevent_update
    return true if self.changed == self.updatable_attributes
    self.errors.add_to_base "Cannot update a #{ self.to_s }"
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I realised that the models that require my prevent_update logic are also those that require the plugin, so I've moved the whole lot into the plugin, using a before_update filter like you suggest.

Comment: In rails 3.*, add the error via `self.errors.add :base, "Cannot update..."`

Comment: I think you likely want the if clause to rather be `return true if self.changed|self.updatabale_attributes == self.updatabale_attributes` so that you can also update a subset of the updatable_attributes.

Comment: from some point the `before_update` callback lost the functionality to prevent update, no matter what it returns, or what errors it adds. Use the validation instead, related question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781183/1527434)

Answer (score 6):

Late to the game here, but for people viewing this question, you can use `attr_readonly` to allow writing to a field on create, but not allowing updates.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods.html

I think it has been available since Rails 2.0

The tricky part is, if you have any attributes that are `attr_accessible` you have to list your read only attributes there also (or you get a mass assignment error on create):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :original_title
  attr_accessible :latest_title, :original_title
end
```

Comment: mdkirby, could you pls take a look at this one? I feel it's connected to this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357501/rails-attribute-changes-in-spite-of-not-being-in-form

Answer (score 0):

Is this to prevent mass assignment? Would attr_accessible / attr_protected not do what you need?

---

Edit, just to illustrate the general point about the callback.

```
 module MyModule
   def MyModule.included(base)
     base.send :alias_method_chain, :prevent_update, :exceptions
   end

   def prevent_update_with_exceptions
   end
 end

 class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_validation :prevent_update

   def prevent_update
   end

   include MyModule
 end
```

Comment: Nope, its to enforce business rules at the model level. Doing attr_readonly for every field except one could do the job, but is rather verbose.

Comment: How about a before_validation callback? You can check which attributes have changed and if the model is new, and then prevent the update?

Comment: Not sure I understand your suggestion completely... you're saying to add a before_validation callback into the model which will prevent updates. Then in my plugin what should I do to allow an update on the one field?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'm understanding what you need to do actually either, but the plugin could just add a callback which uses Rails's partial updates to see which fields have changed and add errors as appropriate.

Comment: Well the error adding functionality is part of the original model behaviour, so by default the model should not be updateable. This can be done either by overriding the update method, or using a callback like you suggest. The issue is how to allow my plugin to update one of the fields? Using callbacks like you suggest I raise an error with !self.new?, but my plugin will still fall foul of that - there's no way for the plugin to override that behaviour. Or is there?

Comment: I see, just define a callback in the model which prevents any updates and then yes you can override it from the plugin with the new behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using alias_method_chain like this in a plugin is slightly flawed though, since the plugin gets included before the original method is defined, so there is no method available to alias.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the rails params.require method to whitelist attributes that you want to allow.

```
def update
  if @model.update(update_model_params)
    render json: @model, status: :ok
  else
    render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private
  def update_prediction_params
    params.require(:model).permit(:editable_attribute)
  end
```